# How to add a directory to PYTHONPATH from CMake?

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I have a c++ library which has a python API library based on Boost.python included in the directory structure.

```
module
|_python_files
|_cpp_files
```

Is there a standard way to configure CMakelist so that it automatically adds the library containing the python files to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: how do you use python in cmake?

Comment: we have some scripts in the python directory, and also the generated .so files from Boost.python go to that library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you use `FindPython` you should be able to use

```
Python_add_library (my_module MODULE src1.cpp)
```

Or you could add the path to PYTHONPATH:

```
list(append PYTHONPATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/module/python_files")
```

Otherwise, you want to add `python_files` to your python definition path:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:../module/python_files"
```

Comment: `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:../module/python_files"` will not work on Windows, where the paths are separated by `;`.

Answer (score 3):

based on [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) this should od the trick:

```
set(ENV{PYTHONPATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/module/python_files")
```

I didn't test that.

Note that `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is read and used by python interpreter not by cmake. It is used when trying locating python libraries imported by python code.